# How to use Spring framework in an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, plugins, pde

I am developing eclipse features and plugins, recently i wanted to start using spring framework, and i wouldn't like to add the spring libraries to my plugin... is there a better solution? for example maven dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert here, but I guess that usage of Spring Framework inside Eclipse plugin isn't the best idea.

If you want IoC and are not happy with the classical `BundleActivator` you can use OSGi Declarative Services.
If you want to use specific classes from Spring, please think about why you actually need them.

Comment: Spring is a good framework with many usefull stuff, not only IoC,
why isn't a good idea to use inside an OSGi environment?

Comment: Yes, it is. I may be wrong, cause I've never tried by myself, but two problems which come to my mind: additional dependencies (more to download, bigger memory consumption), complexity. And beside that: I simply don't know which part of the Spring Framework would be useful for the Eclipse plugin.